# Sending terrain height data with RakNet

Tags: terrain, raknet

I generate a string like so:

```
std::string str = "";
str += std::to_string(MapSize);

for (int x = 0; x < MapSize; x++) {
    for (int z = 0; z < MapSize; z++) {
        str += " ";
        str += std::to_string(x);
        str += " ";
        str += std::to_string(heights[x][z]);
        str += " ";
        str += std::to_string(z);
    }
}
```

The amount of height data is MapSize^2 (MapSize is usually 256x256). But th question is- Is this a sane amount of data to send through RakNet (UDP)? I could split the data into chunks, but i would like to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 1):

RakNet automatically breaks packets up into sane sizes for UDP, somewhere between 574 and 1492 bytes.
This is called the MTU size. accounting for reliability headers or string serialization bloat,

`256x256/574=115 packets minimum
256x256/1492=44 packets minimum`

I recommend setting the reliability type to [`RELIABLE_ORDERED`](http://www.raknet.net/raknet/manual/reliabilitytypes.html), so that the packets are guaranteed to arrive, and in order.

Source: RakNet manual & doxygen, especially [a certain page](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/raknet/manual/programmingtips.html)